# upload images from multiple folders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to upload images from multiple folders into html page. 
For example:

```
first headline
-----first folder images----

second headline
-----second folder images----
```

What I have now is the posibility to upload images from only one folder (i'm using jquery). I don't have and don't need an upload button. Just put the images into a folder, refresh the Html page and the images will be there.
My question is how can i change it to multiple ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dir = "C:\\Pic\\test\\"; 
    var fileextension = ".jpg"; 
    var i = "1";
    $(function imageloop(){
        $('.gallary').prepend('<li><a href="#"><img id="' + i + '" alt="description" /><img id="1' + i + '" alt="description" class="preview" /></a></li>')
            if (i==11){

            }
            else{
            $("#"+i).attr('src', dir + i + fileextension );
            $("#1"+i).attr('src', dir + i + fileextension );
            i++;
                imageloop();
            };
    });   
});

<div>
   <ul class="gallary"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one way you can achieve this by using array to hold directory locations, like var dir = ["C:\Pic\test\", "C:\Pic\test2\"]; and loop through them.

Answer (score 0):

Simply include the files in that document. Honestly just put the pictures into that file. Save you lots of time. If you really need those pics in another file than link that file to your html page.

```
<head>
<link rel="import" href="pictures.html">
</head>

<img src="yourpicture.jpg" width="" height="" style="">
```

Honestly i believe google could have answered this question perfectly fine.

Comment: brandon maybe I explained myself wrong.. 
What i have now is a folder with images that i add or remove. I can't link the html directly to the images (that is the reason i use jquery). It works with one folder.. the question is how i change it to work with multiple folders and show the images in the same html page